# Problem with Dot and FortranForm

Tags: output-formatting, fortran

I am trying to convert some set of equations to a form that will be easy for *Python* to evaluate numerically, hence I am using *Mathematica's* `FortranForm`

My problem is that

`FortranForm[np.diag]`

gives

`Dot(np,diag)`

whereas I want

`np.diag`

I do not want

`FortranForm["np.diag"]`

which results in

`"np.diag"`

What I want is to be able to cast the `DiagonalMatrix[equations]` part of my expressions to the equivalent in *Python* - `np.diag(equations)`, where I have imported `numpy` as `np`

**Solution, but not the desired one**

I found a way round my problem, though it is not what I want, but I will post it for people that my just care about the end result.

Use `FortranForm["np.diag"]` and then export the result to a text file. Then in *Python* one can read the file and rewrite it line by line, while stripping all the quotes using this piece of code

```
def fromMathematica(func):
    """" string -> string 

    Imports a file, created by Mathematica and reads it, so that it can be evaluated for specific values
    """
    file = open('path' + func + .txt' , 'r+')
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.seek(0)
    file.truncate()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.replace('"', '').strip()
        file.write(line)
    file.seek(0)
    m = file.read()
    return m
```

Comment: You have to do some transformations manually. In this case, you might want to use [`StringReplace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace.html).

Comment: I am not sure I see your point. My problem is that if it is a string, `FortranForm` will return it surrounded by quotes, which is what I want to avoid

Comment: I think you are taking an ill-concieved approach trying to use mathematics dot product function to produce a name-scoping construct in python.  Suggest name the function something like `npdotdiag` in mathematica and do a stringreplace on the result. (You should not need to do anything by hand! )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably I don't understand your problem correctly, still giving it a try ..

```
ff = FortranForm[p + DiagonalMatrix[a + b]]
```

> p + DiagonalMatrix(a + b)

```
StringReplace[ToString[ff], "DiagonalMatrix" -> "np.diag"]
```

> p + np.diag(a + b)

Comment: This exactly solves my problem for the moment. I didn't think of replacing stuff after using `FortranForm`. I will see what happens when I try that approach on my pages long equations :)

Answer (score 5):

I would give [`DiagonalMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiagonalMatrix) a custom [`FortranForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FortranForm):

```
Unprotect[DiagonalMatrix];
Format[DiagonalMatrix,FortranForm]=Format["np.diag", OutputForm];
Protect[DiagonalMatrix];
```

Then:

```
ToString[p + DiagonalMatrix[a + b], FortranForm]
```

> "p + np.diag(a + b)"